# Getting a for loop to work with negative numbers

Tags: c, arrays, loops

Write a loop that sets each array element to the sum of itself and the next element, except for the last element which stays the same. Be careful not to index beyond the last element. Ex:
Initial scores:        10, 20, 30, 40
Scores after the loop: 30, 50, 70, 40
The first element is 30 or 10 + 20, the second element is 50 or 20 + 30, and the third element is 70 or 30 + 40. The last element remains the same. 
***This is a homework question that I need help with.***
What I am having problems with is if the bonusScores are negative the example it uses against my code is -100, -200, -300 , -400, -500.

```
include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
    int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];
    int i = 0;

    bonusScores[0] = 10;
    bonusScores[1] = 20;
    bonusScores[2] = 30;
    bonusScores[3] = 40;

    /* Your solution goes here  */
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (( bonusScores[i] <= bonusScores[i +1] ) || (bonusScores[i] < bonusScores [i+1]))
        {
            bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
        }
        else
        {
            bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i];
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", bonusScores[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide expected output and actual output.

Comment: Why should the sign matter at all? Why do you have these comparisons in your code? The whole algorithm should be a single loop with one assignment in it.

Comment: for the first set it works. like 10, 20, 30, 40 the output is 30,50,70,40. However when it uses -100, -200, -300, -400, -500. It should show -300 -500 -700 -900 -500 but mine just shows the original inputs. I have no algorithm as it is an online textbook that only takes code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the assignment there is written

> Be careful not to index beyond the last element

However this loop

```
   for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++)
   {
        if (( bonusScores[i] <= bonusScores[i +1] ) || (bonusScores[i] < bonusScores [i+1]))
        {
            bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
        }
        else
        {
            bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i];
        }
    }
```

tries to use an index beyond the last element when `i` is equal to `SCORES_SIZE - 1`

And there is nothing said in the assignment about this condition

```
if (( bonusScores[i] <= bonusScores[i +1] ) || (bonusScores[i] < bonusScores [i+1]))
```

which is the same as

```
if (( bonusScores[i] <= bonusScores[i +1] ))
```

It is not clear why you wrote this condition.

The loop can look the following way

```
for ( i = 1; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i )
{
    bonusScores[i-1] += bonusScores[i];
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
    int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];

    bonusScores[0] = 10;
    bonusScores[1] = 20;
    bonusScores[2] = 30;
    bonusScores[3] = 40;

    for ( int i = 1; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        bonusScores[i-1] += bonusScores[i];
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%d ", bonusScores[i] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );

    bonusScores[0] = -100;
    bonusScores[1] = -200;
    bonusScores[2] = -300;
    bonusScores[3] = -400;

    for ( int i = 1; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        bonusScores[i-1] += bonusScores[i];
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i )
    {
        printf( "%d ", bonusScores[i] );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Its output is

```
30 50 70 40 
-300 -500 -700 -400
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm really unsure why I had some of those random things in there. Thank you again. Your explanations did a great job explaining where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You made negative numbers an issue by adding that `if` condition inside the loop. It's redundant. You're just asked to take the array and transform it so that element `i` represents `a[i] + a[i+1]` in your original array. This doesn't require any sort of special handling for signs.

Also, note that in your code, you're referring to element `i + 1` when this could potentially be an element beyond the bounds of the array (suppose `i = 3`). When you modify the code to loop correctly, be sure to avoid indexing outside the bounds of the array.

You can completely avoid a check by using an appropriate condition in the `for` loop. Not only does `i` have to be less than  the size of the array, but `i+1` must satisfy this condition too.

Answer (score 2):

You should only iterate through your array `SCORES_SIZE-1` times. Inside the loop simply add current + next and store it into your array, as such:

```
include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
    int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];
    int i = 0;

    bonusScores[0] = 10;
    bonusScores[1] = 20;
    bonusScores[2] = 30;
    bonusScores[3] = 40;

    /* Your solution goes here  */
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE-1; i++)
    {

        bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d ", bonusScores[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the sum of two negatives bonus will be a greater negative bonus, so simply go ahead and add the numbers without bothering to check if they are negative or positive.

Your loop should only run till the numbers you want to update. Since you do not need to update the last number, do not go there.
Other than that I think you are quite on track.

Comment: How would I communicate that into code. This makes sense, and I know it has to do with my if statement, but I don't know how I could figure it out to do all numbers until the last one?

Comment: If you know the total size of your array, it should be easy to stop the loop at the last but one.

Comment: The book just generates the numbers and runs it through the code. I know no idea what the numbers will be until it passes the first set of numbers the book uses.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got and all answers are correct:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class StudentScores {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
  int[] bonusScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length; ++i) {
     bonusScores[i] = scnr.nextInt();
  }

  for(i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE - 1; ++i){
        bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i] + 
bonusScores[i + 1];
     }

  for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length; ++i) {
     System.out.print(bonusScores[i] + " ");
  }

  System.out.println();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is what are you expecting:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    const int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
    int bonusScores[SCORES_SIZE];
    int i = 0;

    bonusScores[0] = -10;
    bonusScores[1] = -20;
    bonusScores[2] = -30;
    bonusScores[3] = -40;

    printf("Negative scores:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(i!=SCORES_SIZE-1)
            bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
      printf("%d ", bonusScores[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    bonusScores[0] = 10;
    bonusScores[1] = 20;
    bonusScores[2] = 30;
    bonusScores[3] = 40;

    printf("Positive scores:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(i!=SCORES_SIZE-1)
            bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
      printf("%d ", bonusScores[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Voici la sortie console :

```
Negative scores:
-30 -50 -70 -40 
Positive scores:
30 50 70 40
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This is the Java version of your problem, if anyone is interested.
public class StudentScores {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
  final int SCORES_SIZE = 4;
  int[] bonusScores = new int[SCORES_SIZE];
  int i = 0;

  bonusScores[0] = 10;
  bonusScores[1] = 20;
  bonusScores[2] = 30;
  bonusScores[3] = 40;

for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE - 1; ++i) {
    bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
    }

for (i = 0; i < SCORES_SIZE; ++i) {
     System.out.print(bonusScores[i] + " ");
    }
     System.out.println();

  return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple loop:

```
/* Your solution goes here  */
  for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length; ++i) 
  {
     if (i == bonusScores.length -1)
     {
        break;
     }
     bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores[i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
  }


  for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length; ++i) 
  {
     System.out.print(bonusScores[i] + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < bonusScores.length - 1; i++)
{
bonusScores[i] += bonusScores[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can add an `||` statement but this helps it add the following element minus the last element since there is none past it.
The issue I see is you account for one element being smaller than the next element but what if its larger? then > before

My solution:

```
for (i = 0; i < bonusScores.length-1; ++i)
     if ( bonusScores[i] <= bonusScores[i +1] )
    {
        bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
    }
    
    else if ( bonusScores[i] >= bonusScores[i +1] )
    {
        bonusScores[i] = (bonusScores [i] + bonusScores[i+1]);
    }
      else {
      bonusScores[i] = bonusScores[i];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Java version answer:

```
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            bonusScores [i] = bonusScores [i] + bonusScores [i+1];
     }
```

Comment: 1) the question is about C, not Java. 2) this adds nothing to existing answers. 3) providing code without any explanations is not very useful.